# c - why escape string if not using sql?

Tags: c, sql-injection

### Context

Learning.

### Question

When we use sql, there is a need to escape user input or better use prepared statements to avoid injections.

Is this need underlying a flaw in the SQL language ?

Imagine I have a http server and that I put the user input directly in a binary file, are there possible injections ?

When I will need to read it again, fopen, fread, fclose and job done, no ? Still not vulnerable I guess (I don't speak about sanitization to avoid xss in the clients browser, just injection).

In the end, sql puts strings in a file too.

So what is the difference ? Is sql language weak ? Is my method at risk(s) ? Why ?

Comment: explained [here](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build an SQL command string, you should always escape the parts of it coming from user input.

Otherwise, use prepared statements.

It is not really a weakness of SQL, but a property of most turing complete interpreted languages. [Code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) can -and does- happen outside of SQL (e.g. in shell scripts, PHP code, etc...)

Read also about [Quine programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) (and google for anti-quotations and quasi-quotations in your programming languages).

Comment: Thanks I am aware of sanitization but i just wanted to be sure no harm could be done if code is not executed. You answered nicely

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on how you interpret the user input. You may be OK if you simply store the user input to relay exactly at a later stage, but in your example, if you read the output and then output it to a webpage, you are opening yourself up to malicious input from the user. Let's say you read from an input field and simply output that directly into the html file and serve it, let's say as a `<p>user text</p>`. If a malicious user knew your layout, they could easily slip some javascript in there. Even worse, if you are generating (say) a `.php` file using this data, a malicious user could craft something that would end up running on your server. Anywhere that there is a layer of interpretation going on you have the risk of injection.

Answer (score 1):

If the user input is executed or is part of something that is executed (sql, html, shell script...) you should always escape it.
If you are just reading values there is no reason to escape it.